# Can I calibrate mouse axis movement angle in Windows 10?

Tags: mouse, axis

I use my mouse at a 45 degree angle. When I move up on the mousepad, I want it to go up on screen, not at 45 degree angle. I remember in older versions of Windows there was a setting for this, but I can’t seem to find it now.

Comment: I had a logitec mouse that came with software that allowed this angle to be set, not native in Windows though.

Comment: mines logitech too, but i cant find any setting in setpoint

Comment: Yeah, they are always changing that software.

Comment: Try the logitec forums...https://community.logitech.com/s/topic/0TO31000000UKNnGAO/mice-and-pointers